# Building a cmake project with a separate resource folder

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project with three folders :

```
project:  main.cpp and CMakeLists.txt
          sub_directory1 :  bunch of *.cpp and *.h  CMakeLists.txt
          sub_directory2 :   .glade files and .txt files
          build
```

I was able to create the library for `sub_directory1` with the resource files in them , but I'd like to organize a bit

an error results, my .cpp files in `sub_directory1` use `sub_directory2` `.txt` and `.glade` files

How can I let cmake know to let the `.cpp` know where `.glade` files and `.txt` files are , then build in the build folder

Comment: How do the .cpp files use the files in sub_directory2 ? Via #include, or is there a custom command executed by cmake ? In any case, cmake does know sub_directory2 as: `$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR)/sub_directory2`

Comment: .txt files are read by .cpp files in sub1  , while .glade files are read by the GTK API that is used by the .cpp files (in sub1)